# Populate selects with multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've a problem trying to populate a couple selects with a multidimensional Array.

For what i understand, i should use javascript, but i don't have a clue why isn't working some stuffs, so here is the code **WITHOUT** the javascript.

```
$turnos= array();
array_push($turnos, array('nombre' => 'Easy Arica - Turno A', 'tipoturno' => '44', 'lugar' => '318', 'horas' => '11:00:00', 'monto' => '24'));
array_push($turnos, array('nombre' => 'Easy Arica - Turno B', 'tipoturno' => '44', 'lugar' => '318', 'horas' => '12:00:00', 'monto' => '24'));
array_push($turnos, array('nombre' => 'Easy Arica - Turno C', 'tipoturno' => '44', 'lugar' => '318', 'horas' => '13:00:00', 'monto' => '24'));
array_push($turnos, array('nombre' => 'Paris Arica - Turno A', 'tipoturno' => '44', 'lugar' => '254', 'horas' => '14:00:00', 'monto' => '24'));
array_push($turnos, array('nombre' => 'Paris Arica - Turno B', 'tipoturno' => '44', 'lugar' => '254', 'horas' => '15:00:00', 'monto' => '24'));
?>
```

then to list them i do it like this

```
<select type="select" style="width: 150px" v-model="att.shift_turnonombre" :disabled="'si' == att.shift_turnoextra ? false : true">
<?php foreach ($turnos as $turno){
    echo '<option value="'.$turno['nombre'].'">'.$turno['nombre'].'</option>';
} ?>
</select>
```

And everything works fine, i can list them without problem, and i can even save the data in the DB.

But what i would like is add another select field and for example if i pick one option with the $turno['nombre'], the second select auto populates with the $turno['tipoturno'] automatically.

The idea would be do it in array, because when i'm done i think all the data will be around 300 Arrays.

Comment: Hello! If the second select's value is going to be decided by the first select, why have it be a select in the first place? What's the purpose of the second select?

Comment: This is called "dependency select". If you Google it, you'll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: @Michael Beeson It doesn't has to be a select, it can be an input.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect, you will require a bit of javascript. Now how you populate the second input depends on if you're willing to use data-* attributes (custom data as attributes) or would rather keep all the data on the server. If the latter, you'll need to use an ajax call. Fro example like in this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5jNAhYcHEI

If you're happy to use "data-*" attributes, you can simply change the select creation to this:

```
<?php foreach ($turnos as $turno){
    echo '<option data-tipoturno="'.$turno['tipoturno'].'"  value="'.$turno['nombre'].'">'.$turno['nombre'].'</option>';
} ?>
```

and then the javascript will be the following:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var child = document.getElementById("child");

parent.addEventListener("change", function() {
  child.value = parent.options[parent.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-tipoturno')
});
```

I've made a snippet using some invented data:

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var child = document.getElementById("child");

parent.addEventListener("change", function() {
  child.value = parent.options[parent.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-tipoturno')
});
```

```html
<form>
<select id="parent">
<option data-tipoturno="5" val="Michael">Michael</option>
<option data-tipoturno="12" var="Sam">Sam</option>
<option data-tipoturno="56" var="Jane">Jane</option>
<option data-tipoturno="24" var="Dave">Dave</option>
</select>
<input id="child" type="text"/>
</form>
```